# Java Using Enums to determine class type

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I have 3 classes `Foo1`, `Foo2`, and `Foo3` and an Object can be any one of those 3 types. A random object is given to me with a field in it stating the type. So like:

```
{
    type: foo1
}
```

Now I can read that value in just fine and I have an enum class like so:

```
public enum ObjectType {
    FOO1,
    FOO2,
    FOO3;
}
```

I want to be able to determine an object's type from the corresponding enum value. So how do I link the enum values to the corresponding classes so that when I read in the `type` value I can tell if the object is of type `Foo1`, `Foo2`, or `Foo3`.

Comment: Ues `instanceof` to determine the  type

Comment: @NullPointerException How exactly? I am parsing a JSON response that contains a type field. So I don't have an object from the get go to use `instanceof`

Comment: Give the enum values a field and initialize it in the constructor, e.g. `FOO1("foo1")`. Also provide a map that maps the enum instance to that field value and query that map with the value you get from your JSON object (or depending on the library you're using you might use a custom deserializer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this (you can edit my code, just the `get(String jsonType)` method, to get the `Class` directly without get the Enum and then the class)

```
public static enum FooClassEnum
{
    Foo1("foo1", FOO1.class),
    Foo2("foo2", FOO2.class),
    Foo3("foo3", FOO3.class);

    private final Class myClass;
    private final String jsonType;

    FooClassEnum(String jsonType, Class myClass){
        this.myClass = myClass;
        this.jsonType = jsonType;
    }

    public static FooClassEnum get(String jsonType) {
        for (FooClassEnum ft : values())
            if (ft.getJsonType().equals(jsonType))
                return ft;
        return null;
    }

    public Class getFooClass() { 
        return myClass; 
    }

    public String getJsonType() {
        return jsonType;
    }
}
```

The use will be like this, assuming the type in your json is `foo1`:

```
FooClassEnum classEnum = FooClassEnum.get("foo1");
Class classOfYourJson = classEnum.getFooClass();
//Cast your object
Object yourObj;
if(classOfYourJson.newInstance() instanceof Foo1) {
    Foo1 f1 = (Foo1) yourObj;
} else if(classOfYourJson.newInstance() instanceof Foo2) {
    Foo2 f2 = (Foo2) yourObj;
} else if(classOfYourJson.newInstance() instanceof Foo3) {
    Foo3 f3 = (Foo3) yourObj;
} else {
   //error
}
```

Comment: I tried doing `classEnum.getFooClass() instanceof Foo1` and I get the error `Error:(36, 54) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Class cannot be converted to ....Foo1`

Answer (score 0):

> So how do I link the enum values to the corresponding classes so that
>   when I read in the type value I can tell if the object is of type
>   Foo1, Foo2, or Foo3.

Add a `Class` field in the `ObjectType` enum, like this

```
public enum ObjectType {
    FOO1(Foo1.class),
    FOO2(Foo2.class),
    FOO3(Foo3.class);

 private Class klass;

 ObjectType(Class klass) {
   this.klass = klass;
 }
 // ... klass getter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is with a map somewhere.

```
{ 
  // define and populate the map
  public static final Map<ObjectType,Class> typeMap;
  static {
    Map<ObjectType,Class> tempMap = new Hashtable<ObjectType,Class>;
    tempMap.add(ObjectType.FOO1,Foo1.class);
    tempMap.add(ObjectType.FOO2,Foo2.class);
    tempMap.add(ObjectType.FOO3,Foo3.class);
    typeMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tempMap);
  }

  // use it
  {
    // actually you probably want a superclass of Foo{1,2,3} ...
    Object newObj = typeMap.get(tempObj.type.toUpperCase()).newInstance();
    newObj.initalizeFrom(tempObj);
```

However, I'm not sure you need the enum.  If the "type" field is actually the class-name, you can reflect on it directly.

```
{
  // ...
  newObj = Class.forName(tempObj.type).newInstance();
```

Or you can do other transformations with a suitable naming standard.

```
{
  // ...
  newObj = Class.forName(PACKAGE + "." 
    + StringUtils.capitalize(tempObj.type) ).newInstance();
```